# Is Odata Filter functions supported in SAP Cloud SDK -Java

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I want to use the OData function SubstringOf in our filter expression. As of now I do not see any relevant api against GeneratedEntityName.PROPERTYNAME.

Is there a workaround to use substringOf incase the API is unavailable.
Using Java SAP Cloud SDK version 3.7.0

Comment: Is your questions related to the Java or JavaScript version of the SAP Cloud SDK?

Comment: Edited the version of the SDK in use

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the feature you are requesting is currently not implemented. Due to dependency restrictions the *SAP Cloud SDK* will not be able to provide a native solution to use custom filter expressions.

```
        new DefaultGeneratedService()
            .getAllEntities()
            .select(Entity.PROPERTY_NAME)
            .withQueryParameter("$filter", "substringof('SAP', CompanyName)")
```

You will not be able to use other `filter` expressions by the VDM. So you have to construct the query string yourself.

We are planning to enable custom and type based filters sometime this year.